# Excel 2010 Cell Selection Macro

Tags: excel, hotkeys, vba

So I'm floored that there is not a hotkey to do this.  I went on Microsoft's site to check the Excel hotkeys and there isn't one.

All I want to do is have a hotkey that copies the contents of a cell that I have currently selected.  I don't want to use my mouse at all.  Is this possible?  The only solution that Microsoft provides is:

1. Hit F2 to edit the contents of the selected cell
2. Select text with Shift+Arrow (Not Ctrl+A mind you, this does not work in a cell)
3. Hit Ctrl+X or Ctrl+C to copy the value.

[Microsoft Description](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/move-or-copy-cells-and-cell-contents-HP010342707.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342321#BMmovecontents)

Why is there not hotkey for this? Can one be made?  It would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: You can replace 2 by `CTRL+SHIFT+End`

Comment: Still, doesn't this seem like something that should be automated?  When I just copy the cell sometimes I'm not pasting in a place that I can just paste plain text, so I get the whole cell.

Comment: you want to only see the text it it were a formula, or include the "=" as well?

Comment: Just copy everything that is in the cell.  The answer below does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to assign the macro to your own hotkey but this will add the ActiveCell text to the clipboard. Add a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

```
Sub hotKeyCopy()
Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim copyText As String
copyText = ActiveCell.Text
DataObj.SetText copyText
DataObj.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice!  Thank you so much.  For anyone that is curious on how to add a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library, in the Microsoft VB for Applications window when making the macro, go to Tools -> References then find Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library in the list.  If its not there, click Browse... and go to c:\windows\system32\FM20.DLL.

Comment: Also, if you can't find it on the list, adding a form to a workbook will automatically set the reference, and you can then remove the form